# How to group each level of json data by one of its common value

Tags: javascript, json

I am facing some problems regarding my project where I am trying to build a tree using JSON data I have something like this

```
var treeData = [
          {
            "name": "Root Node",
            "parent": "null",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": " Transport",
                "parent": "Root Node",
                "nodeId":"nod411",
                "children": [
                      {
                        "name": "Cars",
                        "parent": "Transport",
                        "nodeId":"nodjz13l"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "Transport-2",
                        "parent": "Transport",
                        "nodeId":"nod411",
                        "children": [

                          {
                            "name": "Cars",
                            "parent": "Transport-2",
                            "nodeId":"nod1_cdot"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "Cars",
                            "parent": "Transport-2",
                            "nodeId":"nod45jkl"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "Bikes",
                            "parent": "Transport-2",
                            "nodeId":"nod411"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "Cars",
                            "parent": "Transport-2",
                            "nodeId":"nod961"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "Cars",
                            "parent": "Transport-2",
                            "nodeId":"nodm2m40"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "Bikes",
                            "parent": "Transport-2",
                            "nodeId":"nod411"
                          },
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Cars",
                    "parent": "Transport",
                    "nodeId":"nod411"
                  },

                  {
                    "name": "Cars",
                    "parent": "Transport",
                    "nodeId":"nod311"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Bikes",
                    "parent": "Transport",
                    "nodeId":"nod411"
                  },
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Bikes",
            "parent": "Root Node",
            "nodeId":"nod411"
          }

        ]
      }
    ];
```

where I want to group similar entries based on its value as a key-value pair something like this.

```
var treeData = [
          {
            "name": "Root Node",
            "parent": "null",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": " Transport",
                "parent": "Root Node",
                "nodeId":"nod411",
                "children": [
                    {"key":"car","values":[
                      {
                        "name": "Cars",
                        "parent": "Transport",
                        "nodeId":"nodjz13l"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "Cars",
                        "parent": "Transport",
                        "nodeId":"nod411"
                      },

                      {
                        "name": "Cars",
                        "parent": "Transport",
                        "nodeId":"nod311"
                      }
                     ]
                    },
                  {
                    "name": "Transport-2",
                    "parent": "Transport",
                    "nodeId":"nod411",
                    "children": [
                        {"key":"car","values":[
                              {
                                "name": "Cars",
                                "parent": "Transport-2",
                                "nodeId":"nod1_cdot"
                              },
                              {
                                "name": "Cars",
                                "parent": "Transport-2",
                                "nodeId":"nod45jkl"
                              },
                              {
                                "name": "Cars",
                                "parent": "Transport-2",
                                "nodeId":"nod961"
                              },
                              {
                                "name": "Cars",
                                "parent": "Transport-2",
                                "nodeId":"nodm2m40"
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {"key":"Bikes","values":[
                              {
                                "name": "Bikes",
                                "parent": "Transport-2",
                                "nodeId":"nod411"
                              },
                              {
                                "name": "Bikes",
                                "parent": "Transport-2",
                                "nodeId":"nod411"
                              }
                            ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {"key":"Bikes","values":[
                  {
                    "name": "Bikes",
                    "parent": "Transport",
                    "nodeId":"nod411"
                  }
                ]
               }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Bikes",
            "parent": "Root Node",
            "nodeId":"nod411"
          }

        ]
      }
    ];
```

I want to group data at each level of the tree.

I tried nesting using d3 as

```
var treeDataByName = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .entries(treeData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(treeDataByName));
```

However it transforms only root node into key value pair.

Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: what about the first and second level? do you need a grouping by name as well?

Comment: yes I need grouping at each level whether its first second or last level. and yes I need grouping by name. @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group each array by the wanted key with an iterative (for the actual array) and recursive (with children) approach.

```js
function groupBy(array, key) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(g => g.key === o[key]),
            value = Object.assign({}, o, o.children && { children: groupBy(o.children, key) });

        if (temp) {
            temp.values.push(value);
        } else {
            r.push({ key: o[key], values: [value] });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var tree = [{ name: "Root Node", parent: "null", children: [{ name: " Transport", parent: "Root Node", nodeId: "nod411", children: [{ name: "Cars", parent: "Transport", nodeId: "nodjz13l" }, { name: "Transport-2", parent: "Transport", nodeId: "nod411", children: [{ name: "Cars", parent: "Transport-2", nodeId: "nod1_cdot" }, { name: "Cars", parent: "Transport-2", nodeId: "nod45jkl" }, { name: "Bikes", parent: "Transport-2", nodeId: "nod411" }, { name: "Cars", parent: "Transport-2", nodeId: "nod961" }, { name: "Cars", parent: "Transport-2", nodeId: "nodm2m40" }, { name: "Bikes", parent: "Transport-2", nodeId: "nod411" }] }, { name: "Cars", parent: "Transport", nodeId: "nod411" }, { name: "Cars", parent: "Transport", nodeId: "nod311" }, { name: "Bikes", parent: "Transport", nodeId: "nod411" }] }, { name: "Bikes", parent: "Root Node", nodeId: "nod411" }] }],
    result = groupBy(tree, 'name');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Nina it worked perfectly fine as my need.